# SQL to get teams with no power forward

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I store data about basketball teams in my `Teams` table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Teams (
    Id varchar(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TeamName varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

And I keep team members in `TeamMembers` table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TeamMembers (
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TeamId VARCHAR(5) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Teams(Id),
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PositionId int NOT NULL
);
```

Positions are in another table with `INT` ID's. For example, Guard: 1, Center: 2 and Power Forward: 3 in this exercise.

I want to get a list of basketball teams with NO power forward.

Comment: PositionID should be a FK.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select *
from Teams
where Id not in 
  (
    select TeamId
    from TeamMembers
    where PositionID = 4
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

When checking if a row doesn't exist, use a `NOT EXISTS`!.

```
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    Teams AS T
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'team has no power forward member'
        FROM
            TeamMembers AS M
        WHERE
            M.TeamID = T.ID AND
            M.PositionID = 3) -- 3: Power Forward
```